# How to find the coordinates of the point on a sphere closest to another point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and find the point on it that is closest to the point $(3,1,-1)$ **without using calculus**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point on a surface closest to a point not on the surface (called an "external point") lies on a normal line from the surface point to the external point.  All radii of a sphere are normal (perpendicular) to the sphere's surface.  So the closest point to $ \ (3,1,-1) \ $ will lie along the radius from the origin (the center of the sphere) connecting to that external point.  You need to find the point on the sphere that is found on that line.

Maybe even easier:  the point on the sphere has to be 2 units away from the origin.  Find the line $ ^* $ passing through $ \ (0,0,0) \ $  and  $ \ (3,1,-1) \ $ , then locate the point on that line which is 2 units from the origin.

$ ^* $ EDIT: To remove the ambiguity that I clumsily left, which **Thomas Andrews** properly points out, perhaps I should say "the line segment" connecting the two points.

Comment: There are, of course, two points on that line meeting that condition. You really want the point on a particular ray from $(0,0,0)$...

Comment: True, you would then have to chose the point at the smaller distance from the external point.  The problem is _really_ simple if you use vectors (which aren't generally covered in pre-calculus) and automatically gives you that ray.